# Replace document.write to place HTML content inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, dom-events

I have a JavaScript script (no plugins, just pure JS) that creates an iframe element in the body of the page, and inside this iframe is placed a huge HTML to be displayed in this iframe.

This script uses document.write to write this content to the iframe, however, performance tools report that this procedure is too slow to load the page.

Below is my code:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body'),
    iframe,
    container;

container = document.createElement('div');
container.id = 'iframePlaceholder';

iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = 'myPageIframe';
iframe.name = 'page-content-frame';
iframe.allowfullscreen = true;

container.appendChild(iframe);
body[0].appendChild(container);

iframe = document.getElementById('myPageIframe');

iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write('<html><body>content........<script src="..."></script></body></html>');
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

What can I do to avoid using document.write without having to rewrite all my HTML in DOM?

Is it possible to convert this HTML string into a DOM element and add it to the iframe?

**Edit:**

The content loaded by the iframe is dynamic, so it is not possible to place an HTML file to be loaded by the iframe's SRC.

Comment: So why are you not just opening up an existing HTML document?

Comment: No clue what `What can I do to avoid using document.write without having to rewrite all my HTML in DOM?` is supposed to mean.

Comment: @epascarello This script is a widget that users place on your website and it generates an HTML with dynamic content that is different for each user, it cannot be a unique HTML.
And this Widget can display several different pages depending on the operation that the user is performing.

Comment: I still have no clue what the issue is that you are trying to solve. You have a string[s] and you write it to an iframe. What does DOM have to do with this?

Comment: Have you tried placing that code into a function that is called when the parent document signals document.ready event? That might help with the performance metric.

Comment: Document.write ought to be as fast as any other synchronous approaches. What _exactly_ is the performance tool's objection?

Comment: @Alohci, this is the objection: https://web.dev/no-document-write/?utm_source=lighthouse

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can try placing the HTML content inside a new file and add the name of the file to the src attribute of the iframe.

Something like the following:

```
<iframe id="myPageIframe" name="page-content-frame" src="newfile.html"></iframe>
```